# Sorting an Array of Objects by 2 Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[ {x: 1, y: 4}, {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3},
  {x: 3, y: 4}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 9},
  {x: 2, y: 5}, {x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 2} ]
```

and I'd like to sort it like this:

```
[ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 1, y: 4},
  {x: 2, y: 0}, {x: 2, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5},
  {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 4}, {x: 3, y: 9} ]
```

so the rule is: the array has to be sorted first by the `x` property, and then the sorting by the `y` property has to observe the first sorting.

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
 var elema = a["x"] ;
 var elemb = b["x"] ;
 if (elema < elemb) 
  return -1;
 if (elema > elemb)
  return 1;
 return 0;
});

array.sort(function(a, b){
 var elema = a["y"] ;
 var elemb = b["y"] ;
 if (elema < elemb) 
  return -1;
 if (elema > elemb)
  return 1;
 return 0;
});
```

but it does not work properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it in one function.
Also, if `x` values are the same, you must compare on `y` values.

You can do it this way

```
function SortMyObjects(a, b) 
{
   if (a.x < b.x)
      return -1;

   if (a.x > b.x)
      return 1;

   // a.x == b.x so compare y values
   if (a.y < b.y)
      return -1;

   if (a.y > b.y)
      return 1;

   // perfect equality
   return 0;
}

// sort your array
array.sort(SortMyObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript library. This is an example:

```
var res = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY x,y',[data]);
```

Try this example [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/fyL74rrx/1/).